# apache spark groupBy pivot function

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and using spark 1.6.1. I am using the pivot function to create a new column based on a integer value. Say I have a csv file like this:

```
year,winds
1990,50
1990,55
1990,58
1991,45
1991,42
1991,58
```

I am loading the csv file like this:

```
var df =sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data/sample.csv")
```

I want to aggregate the winds colmnn filtering those winds greater than 55 so that I get an output file like this:

```
year, majorwinds
1990,2
1991,1
```

I am using the code below:
    val df2=df.groupBy("major").pivot("winds").agg(>55)->"count")

But I get this error

```
error: expected but integer literal found
```

What is the correct syntax here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should show what are you expecting as output

Comment: ok thanks. I just updated my question

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you want to filter all winds lower than 55, then group by year and count.

Comment: `agg(>55)->"count")` you have a missing parenthesis here, should be `agg((>55)->"count")`

Answer (score 3):

In your case, if you just want output like:

```
+----+----------+
|year|majorwinds|
+----+----------+
|1990|         2|
|1991|         1|
+----+----------+
```

It's not necessary to use `pivot`.

You could reach this by using `filter`, `groupBy` and `count`:

```
df.filter($"winds" >= 55)
  .groupBy($"year")
  .count()
  .withColumnRenamed("count", "majorwinds")
  .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this generic funtion to do pivot

```
def transpose(sqlCxt: SQLContext, df: DataFrame, compositeId: Vector[String], pair: (String, String), distinctCols: Array[Any]): DataFrame = {
    val rdd = df.map { row => (compositeId.collect { case id => row.getAs(id).asInstanceOf[Any] }, scala.collection.mutable.Map(row.getAs(pair._1).asInstanceOf[Any] -> row.getAs(pair._2).asInstanceOf[Any])) }
    val pairRdd = rdd.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
    val rowRdd = pairRdd.map(r => dynamicRow(r, distinctCols))
    sqlCxt.createDataFrame(rowRdd, getSchema(compositeId ++ distinctCols))
  }
```